# How can an external stylesheet be used to style Polymer 1.0 elements?

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.0 elements contain custom CSS variables that allow you to style them using inline styles as such:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  paper-toolbar {
    --paper-toolbar-color: blue;
  }
</style>
```

This works and is fantastic. How can I accomplish the same, but using an external stylesheet?  Adding `is="custom-style"` to the link tag does not seem to have any effect, as the following does not work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="app.css" is="custom-style">
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can load the HTML file containing your `custom-style` like you would with a polymer element:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-custom-style.html">
```

And your `my-custom-style.html` file would contain:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    paper-toolbar {
        --paper-toolbar-color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

**As of Polymer 1.1, this feature is now deprecated. See [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#external-stylesheets) for an update answer**

Comment: This is the pattern the Polymer team is using for their Paper elements: https://github.com/polymerelements/paper-styles

Comment: But what do you do if you use meteorjs for example, where it takes every css files and concatenates them into one automatically? You have no influence on how the style tag is written in meteor, nor can you import a custom html file with the css (well you could but that means you generate more http requests ofc)

Comment: Please note this method is now deprecated in Polymer 1.1 (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#external-stylesheets). Have a look at my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298500/polymer-import-theme-file-with-host-in-styles-has-no-affect/32302856#32302856) to this question.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out JustinXL. I'll put the link in my answer.