# Polymer @import theme file with :host in styles has no affect

Tags: css, polymer, electron

Back with another Polymer question, I have a Polymer/Electron app that I'm trying to style.

I want to create a `theme.css` that contains a `:host` block with my entire theme in it that I can then import into my modules stylesheet but I've tried a few different things and tried finding anything in the documentation to no avail.

So far, I have tried in, *and* outside of the `<template>` definition:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./account-list.css">` with an `@import`
`<style>@import 'my-theme.css';</style>` just above my `<link>`
`:root` instead of `:host` in my `theme.css`

But neither seem to work, the `theme.css` is definitely being requested but has no affect on the module's style.

Is there anyway to have a theme like this for Polymer, I really don't want to have a build step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a new concept called *style module* (actually a `dom-module` element behind the scene) introduced in Polymer 1.1 (read it [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#style-modules)) and the old way of including external stylesheets has been deprecated (read it [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html#external-stylesheets)).

Basically, you need to create an *html* file like how you normally create an element to store your styles. The `id` defines the name of this file that will be referenced later on.

```
<!-- shared-styles.html -->
<dom-module id="shared-styles">
  <template>
    <style>
      .red { color: red; }
    </style> 
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Then obviously you need to import this file in your page.

```
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">
```

Now, there are two scenarios.

1. If you are using `custom-style` at the document level, you need to
   include the *style module* you previously defined like this -

   `<style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>`
2. If you simply want to include the *style module* inside one of your 
   elements, do this -

   `<dom-module id="my-element">
     <style include="shared-styles"></style>`

Have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fEv4PTjuKXLHvkZiH210?p=preview) that demonstrates both scenarios.

Keep in mind that in your particular example, since you are using `:host`, I assume you will go with scenario 2. So this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bwg6PyMKFMK0eVLPzqdk?p=preview) should be a bit more clearer.

Comment: Will that allow me to use `@apply` as I would like to only allow certain styles  to be changed so I can use `@apply` above any non-changeable styles.

Answer (score 2):

Using dom-module concept, and in order to use a external third party I did the next and it is working, but probably is not a Polymer best practice.

Dom module with 3rd party css (**third-party-styles.html**)

```
<dom-module id="third-party-styles">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/thirdParty/external.css">
</dom-module>
```

I created a container (**elements.html**) where import all needed html modules, and there I registered the third party style module and my module

```
<link rel="import" href="third-party-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="my-module.html">
```

And I added the elements.html in the head of my **index.html**

```
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="import" href="elements.html">
<head>
<body>
    <my-module></my-module>
</body>
```

In my Polymer Element (**my-module.html**)

```
<link rel="import" href="third-party-styles.html">
<dom-module id="my-module">
    <style include="third-party-styles"></style>
    <template>
        <p class=".thirdPartyClass">Content with third party css rule</p>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

any feedback?