# Polymer Iron Flex Mixin's Don't Work, But Classes Do

Tags: dart, polymer, angular-dart

I got Polymer iron-flex-layout to work in my AngularDart component using classes. Since it generates a deprecation warning, I thought would try the recomended alternative: mixin's. They don't work.

Currently, I have this import in my artist_component.dart:

```
import 'package:polymer_elements/iron_flex_layout.dart';
```

I have also tried adding this to my index.html

```
    <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/iron_flex_layout.html">
```

This differs from the example given in the documentation which uses bower. In my artist_component.html I have:

```
<style is="custom-style">
  .container {
   @apply(--layout-horizontal);
  }
  .flexchild {
    @apply(--layout-flex-3);
  }
  .flexchild-2 {
    @apply(--layout-flex-9);
  }
</style>
<section class="container">
  <section class="flexchild gutter">
...
```

I've tried putting the import in index.html and in my main css file along with the styling without affect. Given that classes work you would think mixim's would too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept digging and I found an answer. I also found out that the method has been deprecated. My pubspec defines these versions:

```
polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.17
polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.8
```

I'm pretty sure the solution was to add this line of code to my index.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
```

The reason I'm not positive that this is the only requirement is that I've been changing a lot things to get it to work. This is my complete index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Jazz Cat</title>
<script>
  window.Polymer = window.Polymer || {};
  window.Polymer.dom = 'shadow';
</script>

<!-- For testing using pub serve directly use: -->
<base href="/">
<!-- For testing in WebStorm use: -->
<!-- <base href="/dart/web/"> -->

<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer_elements/iron_flex_layout.html">
<link href="master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style is="custom-style">
  .container {
    @apply(--layout-horizontal);
  }
  .element-index {
    @apply(--layout-flex-3);
  }
  .element-body {
    @apply(--layout-flex-9);
  }
  .element-main {
    @apply(--layout-flex-7);
  }
  .element-sidebar {
    @apply(--layout-flex-2);
  }
</style>
<script defer src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
<script defer src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</head>
<my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</html>
```

Now that I got to work, I'll move my styling to a separate file. This is one of the files where I use the mixin classes:

```
<section class="container">
<section class="element-index">
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <paper-listbox class="scroll-list" (click)="onScroll()">
    <paper-item class="item-height" *ngFor="let artist of artists" [class.selected]="artist == selectedArtist" (click)="onSelect(artist)">
      {{artist.first_name}} {{artist.last_name}}
    </paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
<paper-button (click)="gotoDetail()">Detail</paper-button>
<!--<paper-icon-button icon="refresh" (click)="gotoDetail()"></paper-icon-button>-->
  <!--<button (click)="gotoDetail()">View Details</button>-->
</section>
<section class="element-body">
<div *ngIf="selectedArtist != null">
  <h2>{{selectedArtist.first_name}} {{selectedArtist.last_name}}</h2>
  <!--<section class="layout horizontal">-->
  <section class="container">
    <section class="element-main">
      <!--<dl class="justified">
        <dt>Instrument:</dt><dd>{{ selectedArtist.primary_instrument }} </dd>
        <dt>Other:</dt><dd>{{ selectedArtist.other_instruments }}</dd>
        <dt>Birth:</dt><dd>{{ selectedArtist.birth_year }}</dd>
        <dt>Death:</dt><dd>{{ selectedArtist.death_year }}</dd>
      </dl>-->
      <h3>Notes</h3>
      <p>{{ selectedArtist.notes }}</p>
      <h3>Recordings</h3>
      <table class="index">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Leader</th>
        <tr *ngFor="let credit of artist_credits" >
          <td class="tableDate">{{ credit.recording_date | date:'d MMM yyyy' }}</td>
          <td>{{ credit.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ credit.first_name }} {{ credit.last_name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </section>
    <section class="element-sidebar">
      <dl class="narrow-list">
        <dt>Instrument</dt><dd>{{ selectedArtist.primary_instrument }} </dd>
        <dt>Other</dt><dd>{{ selectedArtist.other_instruments }}</dd>
        <dt>Birth</dt><dd>{{ selectedArtist.birth_year }}</dd>
        <dt>Death</dt><dd>{{ selectedArtist.death_year }}</dd>
      </dl>
    </section>
  </section>
</div>
</section>
</section>
```

Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298500/polymer-import-theme-file-with-host-in-styles-has-no-affect/32302856#32302856), a new method has been created for polymer 1.1 and this one has been deprecated.